# What exactly happens when i write Me.objectcontext in domain service?

Tags: silverlight, objectcontext, domainservices

I searched for the same question over the net for a long time and couldn't find any detailed answer. like this answer :-Gets the ObjectContext for this LinqToEntitiesDomainService(Of TContext).(from msdn).

So my question is

No 1:- exactly ObjectContext Property do in domainservice ?

NO 2:- Can i overloads the property ?

NO 3:- What will happen if i overloads the property ?

The question can be strange but i really want to what exactly happens when i write Me.object context in domain service?

Answer (score 0):

ObjectContext represent your entity models entities and functions.
It provides some methods for running with entities as if they are objects.

You can't override this property. It is not virtual.

It has `SaveChanges`,'ExecuteFunction' like methods .

Beside this you may `extend`your domain service's features by inheritance

```
public partial class DSrvMy : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<AHBSEntitiesMy>
```

You may code a class extends from `LinqToEntitiesDomainService<AHBSEntitiesMy>` it would be your `OwnDomainService`  and then you can override `Invoke` , `Query`,`Submit`,.. like operations in it.

You were be code a layer in ria services.